# How can I resolve these errors from nvim-cmp?

Tags: neovim

So I installed and created the respective configuration according to the official github repo.
I'm using NVIM v0.9.1

When I run `:CmpStatus` it throws me this error

```
Error executing Lua callback: /home/user/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-cmp/plugin/cmp.lua:58: loop or previous error loading module 'cmp'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/user/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-cmp/plugin/cmp.lua:58: in function </home/user/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-cmp/plugin/cmp.lua:57>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This is my `~/.config/nvim/init.lua`

```
--------------------
-- Lazy Bootstrap --
--------------------
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

-------------
-- Plugins --
-------------
local opts = {}
local plugins = {
  ----------------
  -- Aesthetics --
  ----------------
  -- Color Scheme
  "EdenEast/nightfox.nvim",
  -- Contrast tab lines
  "lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim",
  -- UI Focus
  "Pocco81/true-zen.nvim",
  -- Colored Delimeters
  "HiPhish/rainbow-delimiters.nvim",

  -----------
  -- Utils --
  -----------
  -- Treesitter
  {"nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter", build = ":TSUpdate"},
  "nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter-textobjects",
  -- Fuzzy finder
  {
    "nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim",
    tag = "0.1.2",
    dependencies = { "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim" }
  },
  -- Manipulating delimeters (parenthesis, brackest, quotes, etc)
  "kylechui/nvim-surround",
  -- Comments
  "numToStr/Comment.nvim",
  -- Auto pairs
  {
    'windwp/nvim-autopairs',
    event = "InsertEnter",
    opts = {} -- this is equalent to setup({}) function
  },

  ----------------
  -- Completion --
  ----------------
  -- CMP
  "neovim/nvim-lspconfig",
  "hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp",
  "hrsh7th/cmp-buffer",
  "hrsh7th/cmp-path",
  "hrsh7th/cmp-cmdline",
  "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",

  ---------------
  -- Snippets ---
  ---------------
  {
    "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip",
    -- follow latest release.
    version = "2.*", -- Replace <CurrentMajor> by the latest released major (first number of latest release)
    -- install jsregexp (optional!).
    build = "make install_jsregexp"
  }

}


-------------
-- Imports --
-------------
require("lazy").setup(plugins, opts)
require("keymaps")
require("options")
require("ui")
require("delimeters")
require("comment")
require("surround")
require("rainbow_deli")
require("zen")
require("cmp")
```

And my `~/.config/nvim/lua/cmp.lua`

```
-- Set up nvim-cmp.
local cmp = require'cmp'

cmp.setup({
snippet = {
  -- REQUIRED - you must specify a snippet engine
  expand = function(args)
    vim.fn["vsnip#anonymous"](args.body) -- For `vsnip` users.
    require('luasnip').lsp_expand(args.body) -- For `luasnip` users.
    -- require('snippy').expand_snippet(args.body) -- For `snippy` users.
    -- vim.fn["UltiSnips#Anon"](args.body) -- For `ultisnips` users.
  end,
},
window = {
  -- completion = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
  -- documentation = cmp.config.window.bordered(),
},
mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.insert({
  ['<C-b>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(-4),
  ['<C-f>'] = cmp.mapping.scroll_docs(4),
  ['<C-Space>'] = cmp.mapping.complete(),
  ['<C-e>'] = cmp.mapping.abort(),
  ['<CR>'] = cmp.mapping.confirm({ select = true }), -- Accept currently selected item. Set `select` to `false` to only confirm explicitly selected items.
}),
sources = cmp.config.sources({
  { name = 'nvim_lsp' },
  -- { name = 'vsnip' }, -- For vsnip users.
  { name = 'luasnip' }, -- For luasnip users.
  -- { name = 'ultisnips' }, -- For ultisnips users.
  -- { name = 'snippy' }, -- For snippy users.
}, {
  { name = 'buffer' },
})
})

-- Set configuration for specific filetype.
cmp.setup.filetype('gitcommit', {
sources = cmp.config.sources({
  { name = 'git' }, -- You can specify the `git` source if [you were installed it](https://github.com/petertriho/cmp-git).
}, {
  { name = 'buffer' },
})
})

-- Use buffer source for `/` and `?` (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
cmp.setup.cmdline({ '/', '?' }, {
mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
sources = {
  { name = 'buffer' }
}
})

-- Use cmdline & path source for ':' (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
sources = cmp.config.sources({
  { name = 'path' }
}, {
  { name = 'cmdline' }
})
})

-- Set up lspconfig.
local capabilities = require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()
-- Replace <YOUR_LSP_SERVER> with each lsp server you've enabled.
require('lspconfig')['clangd'].setup {
capabilities = capabilities
}
```

And when I run `nvim` it shows me this message:

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:94: loop or previous error loading module 'cmp'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:94: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I then press enter and it continues with this error message:

```
Error detected while processing /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:
E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:94: loop or previous error loading module 'cmp'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /home/user/.config/nvim/init.lua:94: in main chunk
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Then the same error message but for **cmp_buffer.lua** and **cmp_cmdline.lua**.

When I try to enter some text in NeoVim it shows me this

```
Error detected while processing InsertEnter Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: ...l/share/nvim/lazy/cmp-nvim-lsp/lua/cmp_nvim_lsp/init.lua:102: loop or previous error loading m
odule 'cmp'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...l/share/nvim/lazy/cmp-nvim-lsp/lua/cmp_nvim_lsp/init.lua:102: in function <...l/share/nvim/lazy/cmp-nvim-lsp/lua/cmp
_nvim_lsp/init.lua:101>
```

What do you think could be the problem, an installation problem perhaps?
I tried uninstalling neovim and installing everything again with no success at all!

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) don't post your whole config; use [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) to see how to find a minimal config that reproduces the problem. Once you have that, [edit] to replace the long config block with just the minimal example. (2) Try to get some support from the plugin maintainers (often via GitHub or a similar site). They know the code best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problems were gone when i uninstalled neovim completely and instead of naming it `cmp.lua` i used `plg_cmp.lua` i guess `cmp.lua` is used by the plugin itself and that's why it was causing errors.